# Change the view for different devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a project that will works only in iphone, for versions 4, 5 and 6. In my case I am using xib files, in this case I created a class called ViewController with xib file then created three more xib files, causing you to have the following structure:

```
ViewController.h
ViewController.m
ViewController.xib
ViewController4inch.xib
ViewController47inch.xib
ViewController55inch.xib
```

Inside my ViewController.m I put this code inside ViewDidLoad, to recognize the version of the iphone and change the view to the User:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

        ViewController *extratoVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];

        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480){

            // 4-4s
        extratoVC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

        }

        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568){

            // 4-inch
        extratoVC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController4inch" bundle:nil];

        }

        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667){

            // 4.7-inch
        extratoVC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController47inch" bundle:nil];

        }

        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 736){

            // 5.5-inch
        extratoVC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController55inch" bundle:nil];

        }

        [self presentViewController:extratoVC animated:YES completion:nil];// this line causing problem that you see below...

    }

}
```

Unfortunately this code does not work and I get the following error message:

```
Thread1: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0xbf72bfbc)
```

In my project all views will be processed by classes **ViewController.h / .m**

In my case, I am doing through the process .xib files and would not want to use storyboards, anyone know why this problem is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: This is not good practice. Why don't you using auto layout with constraints?

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint on the if statement and step through?  What line does it through the exception on?

Comment: Imagine what would happen if you tried to do this in an Android app. Does this give you any insight as to why it might be a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice. But if you want to find where your code breaks, you can add an exception breakpoint. Like here is explained: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the view inside `viewDidLoad`. This method is always called AFTER the initialization process. You can't init the view there.

Where are you initializing **ViewController**? At that point you should call `initWithNibName:` with the proper xib file name. Then, present the viewController.

Besides this, I strongly suggest you to use a more updated way to achieve this. For example, you can try Size classes so you can have just one storyboards configured for several devices. Here: http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2014/6/12/size-classes-with-xcode-6-and-swift.

Hope this helps!